# Change CALayer properties: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I'm trying to implement selection of a subLayer by clicking on it and visualize that it is had been selected by for example changing the background color of the subLayer.  However, I end up with the following error whatever and however I attempt to change any property:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Her is my function that is called from my `NSView`sub class' `mouseUp`function.

```
func SelectObject( atPoint: NSPoint)
{
    let thePoint = atPoint as CGPoint
    if let hitLayer = itsCourseLayer.hitTest( thePoint) {
        if (hitLayer != itsCourseLayer) {
            // Gives following error:
            // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
            hitLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor 
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried *hitLayer.setValue( NSColor.red.cgColor, forKeyPath: "backgroundColor")* and I've tried to surround it with *CATransaction.begin()* and *CATransaction.commit()*, or to change any other property of the subLayer. But with no success.

Any Idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the exception? What is the output of `po hitLayer` in the debugger?

Comment: `CPCoursePointLayer.swift: 11: 7: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(layer:)' for class 'CoursePlanner.CPCoursePointLayer'` - doesn't make sense to me...  (CPCoursePointLayer is a subclass of *CAShapeLayer* and it's an instance of this class that I get returned from *hitTest*)

Comment: `"warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available."`

Answer (score 5):

The error message is kind of telling you one solution: implement `init(layer:)` in `CPCoursePointLayer`.

When you set a property on a layer, and that layer is in a non-hidden window's layer tree, Core Animation looks for a `CAAction` for that property, by sending [the `actionForKey:` message](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410844-action) to the layer. If that search returns `nil`, Core Animation creates an implicit animation for the property using some default parameters.

Any layer with an attached animation has a corresponding presentation layer. (Read [Layer Trees Reflect Different Aspects of the Animation State](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW19) for more info.) So Core Animation needs to create the corresponding presentation layer for your `hitLayer`. It does this using the `init(layer:)` initializer on your `CPCoursePointLayer` class.

In Swift, a class doesn't automatically inherit all of its superclass's constructors, so your `CPCoursePointLayer` class doesn't have that initializer. So your app crashes.

One solution is to add the `init(layer:)` initializer to your `CPCoursePointLayer` class:

```
init(layer: CALayer) {
    let layer = layer as! CPCoursePointLayer
    // copy any custom properties from layer to self here
    super.init(layer: layer)
}
```

If you define `init(layer:)`, then you can animate properties of your layer, and allow them to be implicitly animated.

If you never plan to explicitly or implicitly animate properties of your layer, then you can instead disable implicit animations by returning `NSNull` when Core Animation searches for an action, for example by adding this method to your `CPCoursePointLayer` class:

```
override class func defaultAction(forKey key: String) -> CAAction? {
    return unsafeBitCast(NSNull(), to: CAAction?.self)
}
```

Comment: Implementing `init(layer:)`did not help. But, overriding `defaultAction` did. I don't need this to be animated in any case, so it's sufficient for me. Thanks for thorough explanation, Rob!