# CAShapeLayer changing lineWidth causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, line, cashapelayer

So I have this nice subclass which may be resized at some point and then I call updateFrame()
Changing lineWidth to any value will produce a crash. What I need is to be able to change lineWidth without animation(instantly).

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/24/a93765689e524d45116f942ce734275e-full.png

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/24/12a880d41cff1f69ef6bd2f974033627-full.png

```
class OvalLayer: CAShapeLayer {

func updateFrame(_ with: CGRect) {
    let newFrame = with.insetBy(dx: frame.size.width * 0.07, dy: frame.size.height * 0.07)
    path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: newFrame).cgPath
    lineWidth = (min(frame.size.width, frame.size.height) / 50) //if i remove this line it will be ok
}

init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init()
    self.frame = frame
    let newFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: frame.size.width * 0.07, dy: frame.size.height * 0.07)
    lineWidth = (min(frame.size.width, frame.size.height) / 50)
    strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: newFrame).cgPath
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Comment: If you are crashing then it seems that the layer that you have called `updateFrame` on is no long a valid object.  Can you post details in the crash log?  How are you obtaining the frame you are calling `updateFrame` on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes a minute later I wrote a solution. I think when you update the layer properties it re-inits from itself (just my guess)

```
override init(layer: Any) {
    super.init(layer: layer)
}
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262678/77567) informative.